# How would I make this image not interfere with position of the title

Tags: html, css

Here is what it looks like:
[image]

If I remove the image, the text centers perfectly:
[image]

@A.B

I mean, it worked... Sort of.
[image]

I am having some problems with the image pushing the title to the right, as you can see, it's not exactly centred.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name"description" content"Mobile Cat Grooming Service">
    <meta name"keywords" content"Cat, Grooming, Service, Colchester">
    <meta name"author" content"Jordan Downs">
    <title>Index</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="master.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeFontSize(element, step) {
    var el = document.getElementById(element);
    var curFont = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(el).fontSize, 10);
    el.style.fontSize = (curFont + step) + 'px';
    }
    </script>
    <script>
function changecolor(code) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor=code
}
</script>
</head>
    <h2>
        <center>
        <button type="button" onClick="changeFontSize('content', 2);">A+</button>
        <button type="button" onClick="changeFontSize('content', -2);">A-</button>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <form>
        <input type="button" name="Button1" value="Default" onclick="changecolor('white')">
        <input type="button" name="Button1" value="Scheme 1" onclick="changecolor('#FE2EF7')">
        <input type="button" name="Button1" value="Scheme 2" onclick="changecolor('#FA58D0')">
        <input type="button" name="Button1" value="Scheme 3" onclick="changecolor('#B404AE')">
    </form>
        </center>
</h2>
<body>
    <div id="page">
    <header>
        <img src="Images/catlogo.jpg" alt= "logo"/>
        <h1><center>Mobile Cat Grooming Service</center></h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
        <li><a alt="Home button" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a alt="History page button" href="history.html">History</a></li>
        <li><a alt="Appointment page button" href="appointments.html">Appointments</a></li>
        <li><a alt="Contact us page button" href="contactus.html">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</head>
```

CSS:

```
 body {
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    zoom: 150%;
}

#page {
    margin:2% auto;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}



header {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 96%;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #660066;
    padding: 1%;
    margin-left: 1%;    
}

header img {
  float: left;
  width: 12%;
  height: 12%;
  background: #660066;

 }


h2 {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: -1%;
    width: 96%;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #660066;
    padding: 1%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    border-color: #Cc3399;
}
nav {
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}


nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 0;
    width: 100px;
    background: #Cc3399;
    color: #eee;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background: #660066;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: there is no image on the link.

Comment: Check this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/gkyrvdpL/) I think everything goes well

Comment: Also the `center` tag has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: do you wanna horizontally center or vertically.

Comment: @lolka_bolka I uploaded it instead.

Comment: @Benjamin I see no change in the code?

Comment: @Paulie_D I removed the center tag and the text aligned to the left instead.

Comment: @Jurdun Yes, it will do that. Use `text-align:center` on the heading tag instead. http://jsfiddle.net/gkyrvdpL/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there is something we're not seeing as your existing code seems to be fine although I have removed the `center` tag which has been deprecated and substituted `text-align:center`.

If it still doesn't center in your FULL HTML, then we need to examine the remainder of the code.

```css
header {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 96%;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #660066;
    padding: 1%;
    margin-left: 1%;    
}

header img {
  float: left;
  width: 12%;
  height: 12%;
  background: #660066;

 }

header h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt= "logo"/>
    <h1>Mobile Cat Grooming Service</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: Theres the rest of the code that i feel would be most relevant

Comment: You've changed the code from the original question. the image is no longer floated and now has position absolute.

Comment: Whoops sorry, let me change that back.

Comment: The new code looks messed up. You have the `body` inside the `head`, an `h2` outside of the `body`. Any and in any case, that `h2` should be a `div` which should not be floated.. You really need to start all over again with correct elements and layout.

Comment: I think I'm just going to remove the logo and make some adjustments. It's all due in tomorrow so starting over again is not an option. Thanks for your help I will mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
header {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 96%;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #660066;
    padding: 1%;
    margin-left: 1%;    
    position:relative;
}
header img {

  width: 12%;  
  height: 12%;  
  background: #660066;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to do this, you could use `position:absolute;` in your image or a more extendable way would be something like this:

```
<header>
    <img src="Images/catlogo.jpg" alt= "logo"/>
    <h1 class="centerTitle">Mobile Cat Grooming Service</h1>
</header>
```

css:

```
centerTitle {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -12%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you want your image aligned compared to the page and/or the header but the reason the image is pushing your `h1` over is because it is being floated and therefore taken out of the normal document flow. The `h1` lines itself up as if the floated image wasn't there. The reason the `h1` is shift over is that the space it takes up is still respected even though it is taken out of the normal document flow.

I can make further suggestions once I know the desired layout.

**EDIT 1**

I would probably use [absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) to solve this.

```html
<header>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/200/city">    
    <h1>Your Title Here</h1>
</header>
```

```css
header {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
header img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1; /* use this if you're having stacking issues */
}
```

Here is a jsFiddle demonstrating the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/3h5zdzbr/1/

Comment: I want it next to the text, where it is but not pushing the text to the right. Exactly where everything is, the only problem is that it's pushing it. you're saying it's because it's floated? What would I do to fix this, I removed the float but it rendered the same result.

Comment: That had the same result as A.B's answer. look at the question for the image.

Comment: The fiddle works so there must be something else going on with your code.

Comment: I've linked the rest of the code that may possibly be relevant